# svcで学習実行時のエラー: ValueError: 'rdf' is not in list

Tags: python, python3

以下の実行時にエラーになります。
学習前に間違ってる場所はありますでしょうか？
アドバイスよろしくお願いします。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

iris = datasets.load_iris()
x = iris.data[:, [2,3]]
y = iris.target

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

svc = svm.SVC(C=1, kernel='rdf', gamma=0.001)
svc.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

**実行結果**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-6880a99bdee3> in <module>
      1
      2 svc = svm.SVC(C=1, kernel='rdf', gamma=0.001)
----> 3 svc.fit(x_train, y_train)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    207 
    208         seed = rnd.randint(np.iinfo('i').max)
--> 209         fit(X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed=seed)
    210         # see comment on the other call to np.iinfo in this file
    211 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py in _dense_fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed)
    266                 cache_size=self.cache_size, coef0=self.coef0,
    267                 gamma=self._gamma, epsilon=self.epsilon,
--> 268                 max_iter=self.max_iter, random_seed=random_seed)
    269 
    270         self._warn_from_fit_status()

sklearn/svm/libsvm.pyx in sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit()

ValueError: 'rdf' is not in list
```

Answer (score 0):

`'rdf'` ではなく `'rbf'` ではないでしょうか。

`ValueError: 'rdf' is not in list` というエラーは、`svm.SVC` の `kernel` に渡せる文字列は以下のものに限られているのに、その一覧リストに `'rdf'` が載っていない、ということを言いたいのだと思います。

> **kernel : string, optional (default=’rbf’)**
>   Specifies the kernel type to be used in the algorithm. It must be one of ‘linear’, ‘poly’, ‘rbf’, ‘sigmoid’, ‘precomputed’ or a callable.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html

Comment: Typeミスでした。ありがとうございます！